# Exogeneity Check of Control Variables? Covariance

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, covariance, controlling-for-a-variable, exogeneity

I have performed an exogeneity check on my control variables to assess their validity before incorporating them into my regression analysis. Upon conducting the analysis, I observed a significant correlation (P-value < 0.01) between three of my control variables and the independent variable. I assume that means there is covariance, should I exclude them as control variables? Or how do I go about deciding if the control variable should be included or not?